# What does “being had” mean in “due regard being had to”?

Tags: phrases

What exactly is meant by *due regard being had to*?

I can’t understand the use of *being had* in such sentences.

I mean only that *due regard to* can be used instead of it.

Comment: It means it was probably written by a lawyer; why use "considering" when you can use 5 words that almost but not quite mean the same thing 

Comment: Haha..thank Dale..and yes..I was reading a law book. :D

Comment: Where it a chemistry book, the sentence might have read"due regard being had to avoid dropping the sodium in the water". We wouldn't want any explosions, would we?

Comment: Does it mean that we use 'due regard being had to' to show attention, concern or notice?..like in an example- Court  can order for winding up of company due regard being had to the interest of the creditors.

Comment: @SaloniAgarwal Yes; unless the rest of the sentence has some odd construction which negates the usual meaning.

Comment: If you're not a lawyer, I wouldn't recommend using *"due regard for being had"* for anything; it's a difficult-to-understand phrase that can usually be replaced by something shorter and more comprehensible.

Comment: It's a horrible phrase; "have/having due regard" is a bit better, and should let you see where it comes from.

Comment: I would understand "due regard being *given* to" or "due regard being had *for*" but not "due regard being had to". Could you please quote a full sentence?

Comment: “due regard being had to” = "while at the same time giving due consideration to'.

Answer (score 0):

"due regard being had to" has often been used by the British lawyers who have been decorated with honors. There is nothing wrong with that usage. That is the correct English.

Answer (score -1):

Being Had: I have always heard this term used for one who has just been fleeced, fooled , or led down a winding garden path to nowhere by a clever scoundrel or fraud.
Examples: A victim tells his tale of woe to a close friend after someone has defrauded him out of a sum of money for a job never done. Friend 1's lament: "I've been had!" I smile to myself when I hear a departing gust say to his host after a television interview: "Thanks for having me on!" REALLY!

Comment: The OP is asking about 'being had' as part of a longer phrase. (Though this is true and funny, it is only tangential to the question.)